# Send checkbox value

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm new at PHP and I need some help with my code.

The problem : I want to send a mail with checkbox values if they are checked, but I can't, and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Here's my code.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="jours">Choix des jours de travail</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="time[]"value="Lundi"> Lundi
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="time[]"value="Mardi"> Mardi
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="time[]"value="Mercredi"> Mercredi
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="time[]"value="Jeudi"> Jeudi
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="time[]"value="Vendredi"> Vendredi
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="time[]"value="Samedi"> Samedi
    </label>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'maxmaxstudio2@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";

$email_body = "Vous avez recu un nouveau message\n\n"."Voici les détails:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n
\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message\n\nThe client want help in these days: $time\n";

$headers = "From: maxmaxstudio2@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['time'] as $value)
  {
     echo 'checked: '.$value.'';
     // insert your email code here
  }
?>
```

Comment: I try it but after clicking on send i get error message : No arguments Provided!

Comment: @MaxSadowski — Well that has nothing to do with the checkboxes. That's your test at the top of the PHP aborting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it ! :)

```
<?php
  $name    = $_POST['name'];
  $email    = $_POST['email'];
  $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
  $message    = $_POST['message'];
  $time = nl2br(implode(',', $_POST['time']));

    $to = 'maxmaxstudio2@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
    $email_subject = "Demande d'aide-ménagère:  $name";

    $email_body =
    "Vous avez recu un nouveau message de:$name\n
    \n"."Voici les détails:\n
    Nom: $name\n
    Email: $email\n
    Téléphone: $phone\n
    Message:\n$message\n
    \nThe client want help in these days: $time";

  $headers = "From: maxmaxstudio2@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

**The solution was $time = nl2br(implode(',', $_POST['time']));**
Found it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967745/post-multiple-checkbox-values-into-php-email)