# Finding out the clicked option from dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown menu where a few of the options are selected and a few are not selected. When I click on any option, I want to find that particular option and check if it is selected or not.

This is what I do right now:

HTML code:

```
<select class="ss-select" data-dropup-auto="false" id="ss_options" multiple="multiple" name="ss">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

This is jQuery code:

```
$("#ss_options").change(function(){
    $('#ss_options').find('option').not(':selected').each(function(k,v){
        console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
    });
    $('#ss_options option:selected').each(function(k,v){
        console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
    });
});
```

Right now I iterate over list of all the selected and unselected option everytime there is a change event. Ideally, I want to process only the element which is selected or unselected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Right now I iterate over list of all the selected and unselected option everytime there is a change event. Ideally, I want to process only the element which is selected or unselected.

To do this in a cross-browser fashion, you'll need to remember which elements were selected previously and then use that information to figure out which element was selected on "this" change. That's because some browsers (Safari, I think) don't provide a `click` event on `option` elements, just the `change` event on the `select`. You can't tell from the `change` event which specific option the change relates to.

Of course, on browsers where `click` on options *is* supported, you can listen for `click` on the `option` elements, but again, not cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used an array to store the previously selected element. And by finding the difference, I achieved the solution. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a dropdown, you could use a group of checkboxes that returns an array of all checked boxes like in this question [Make array from checkbox form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516847/make-array-from-checkbox-form) . I believe this would avoid cross browser support issues like [T.J. Crowder mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713546/3281032)